# How do I convert a string into a .Net DateTime object using a nonstandard format?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having difficulty figuring out the correct way to convert a nonstandard format string into a DateTime object.

Consider the following string:

> Mon Nov 25 14:07:13 2019

I'm attempting to convert using the following code snippet with a custom format:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var sInstallDate = "Mon Nov 25 14:07:13 2019";
DateTime.TryParseExact(sInstallDate, "0:ddd MMM d h:mm:ss tt yyyy", provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

The format I'm using does not work, it throws an exception.
How do I complete this conversion?

Comment: It's not clear why you've started the format string with "0:" when that isn't in the value. Beyond that, it looks like it should have `HH` rather than `h`, and no `tt` part. You should check every part of your format string against your value *really* carefully. (And I don't think that code would throw an exception - it would just return false.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var sInstallDate = "Mon Nov 25 14:07:13 2019";
DateTime.TryParseExact(sInstallDate, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out var parsedDate);
```

Just slightly adjusting the format string to `ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy` results in `11/25/2019 2:07:13 PM`.

---

You need to use `HH` because the hour is in 24 hours format, while `h` expects 12. `H` would also work, if your input hour does not have a leading zero on single digit hours, but based on your minutes, the leading zero would be consistent.

The `tt` can be removed, because there is no "AM" / "PM" designator in your input, as it is covered by the 24 hour format.

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the `0:`, but it was causing issues. The `0` would be treated as a literal, meaning your input would have been required to start with "0", which it didn't. The `:` is treated as a time separator, which would have really confused the parser in that location. Removing these characters allowed the string to be parsed correctly.

---

If needed, all custom format strings can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

---

As a side note, the exception you were getting must have been coming from a different part of your code. `TryParseExact` won't throw an exception if it fails to parse the input string with the given format, it will just return `false`.